# How to get GNU parallel on Amazon Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2, gnu-parallel

Preferably without having to compile it from source. I tried adding repositories I found on Google: [CentOS 6](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tange/CentOS_CentOS-5/home:tange.repo) and [CentOS 5](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/tange/CentOS_CentOS-6/home:tange.repo), but both give me:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-202 yum.repos.d]$ sudo yum install parallel -y
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/2016.03                                                                                                                                                                                                  | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/2016.03                                                                                                                                                                                               | 2.3 kB     00:00
952 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package parallel.noarch 0:20160522-1.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/fish for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/ksh for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/zsh for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/pdksh for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/ksh for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/zsh for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/bin/fish for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/pdksh for package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch (home_tange)
           Requires: /bin/pdksh
Error: Package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch (home_tange)
           Requires: /usr/bin/fish
Error: Package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch (home_tange)
           Requires: /usr/bin/zsh
Error: Package: parallel-20160522-1.1.noarch (home_tange)
           Requires: /usr/bin/ksh
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: That's odd.  I see no reason why gnu parallel would need any of those.  Shouldn't need to be compiled from source, though... GNU parallel is written in Perl.

Comment: (GNU Parallel does not need the shells. But it supports them, and thus refers to them. I do not know how to tell RPM that these are not required, but that GNU Parallel will only use them if you ask it to. If you know how to do a .spec-file the problem is in the env_parallel.* files.)

Answer (score 4):

Installation can be done in less than 10 seconds if you follow the official installation instructions:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

Comment: `GNU parallel-20201022 installed globally
# parallel
bash: parallel: command not found`

Comment: @Petah That sounds weird: When installed globally it is installed in `/usr/bin/parallel`. What does this show: `ls -l /usr/bin/parallel`? Can you run `/usr/bin/parallel`? What is your `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the answer for current Amazon Linux versions, parallel is available in EPEL repository.

Here is information how to enable / install EPEL repository: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/

After it's done install GNU parallel with `sudo yum instal parallel`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with pdksh but was able to work around it. I was able to install GNU parallel without pdksh, and thus didn't have any errors, by:

1. Downloading [rpmforge](http://repoforge.org/use/)
2. rpm installing rpmforge
3. yum installing parallel.

Comment: Since the OP mentioned attempts for following the CentOS 6 instructions to installing parallel and got the same errors as I did, I figured that instructions that did work for me on CentOS 6 (which I posted) would work on his amazon instance. If that doesn't make sense to you I'm happy to delete the answer and post as a comment - I just wanted to provide info for people who were running into the same issue (this question was one of the top search results when I was looking for a solution.)